# Find the largest interior rectangle composed of partitioning rectangles

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry

Suppose a rectangle $R$ is partitioned into more than one smaller rectangles of positive area. What is the fastest algorithm to find the largest rectangle strictly within the all-enclosing rectangle $R$ that is a union of the partitioning rectangles? Of course the dumbest algorithm is simply taking all distinct pairs of partitioning vertices as the diagonal vertices of candidate rectangles, then checking for the admissibility of such candidate rectangles, then computing their areas. The complexity of this dumb algorithm is of course quadratic with respect to the number of partitioning vertices.